# What is the official pronunciation for "SQLite"?

Tags: sqlite

In the name "SQLite", the "L" does double duty, which is clever. But it leads inexorably to the question of how it should be pronounced. Which one of these is the correct pronunciation?

- sql lite (use the L twice)
- sql ite
- sq lite

What is the official pronunciation used and/or promoted by the development team?

Comment: **[SQLite: The Database at the Edge of the Network with Dr. Richard Hipp](https://youtu.be/Jib2AmRb_rk?t=50)**

Comment: 00:47 *I don't care how you pronounce it*

Comment: He mumbles his way through it. I think he's saying "sql lite" but it might be "sq lite".

Comment: Also see [What is the correct pronunciation of SQLite?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431329/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-sqlite)

Comment: Please note that this question asks for an official answer. It's therefore not opinion based. There will only be one answer at most.

Comment: How is this a programming problem?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 13, accepted):

drh [says](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/SQLite-Pronunciation-td88186.html#message88194):

> I wrote SQLite, and I think it should be pronounced "S-Q-L-ite".  Like
>   a mineral.  But I'm cool with y'all pronouncing it any way you want.
>   :-)

Comment: I love when the official answer is "Do whatever, I don't care"